# aws - secrets manager - how to secure secrets when I want to access from ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-secrets-manager

I have been trying to secure my `api_key` and `token`. I thought about using `aws secrets`.

1- If I access the `api_key` and `token` from within my code on `ec2` instance then essentially anyone who gains access to the `ec2` has access to the secret. In essence no extra security?

2- If I use `lambda` to access the `api_key` and `token` and store the resulting value in a `database` and access the database from `ec2` again I don't see the additional security here.

Am I missing something? Or is there a more secure way of storing and accessing the secret and keeping it inaccessible from `ec2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. If somebody can access your Amazon EC2 instance, then they would be able to assume the permissions granted to the instance via the IAM Role.

Therefore, you should ensure that you limit access to the Amazon EC2 instance.

In fact, some organizations take the step of **removing login access to production EC2 instances**. This is done for security, but also to limit changes that are made outside of a controlled process. For example, if there was a problem on an instance and an Administrator logs in and does a quick fix, then there would be no record of that fix. The correct way would be to make a fix in the code and then deploy a *new* instance with that fix (then terminate the old instance).

Other ways to limit access to an EC2 instance are:

- Restrict IP address ranges in Security Groups
- Use Keypairs, not passwords
- Disable SSH and instead access via AWS Systems Manager Session Manager -- all such connections are logged by AWS and access is controlled by IAM rather than Keypairs

Comment: Very insightful, I will have to look into streamlining the process of deployment. The first two bullet points I will implement asap. Already using key pairs. SSH disable is something I will look into more. Thanks a lot.